# Pasting Multiple Excel Charts One Per Row with VBA in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I am trying to copy multiple charts from Excel into Outlook, each as a bitmap, and each on its line and of the same size. The code below loops through copying each chart and successfully pasting them all as bitmaps into Outlook. However, they all occur right next to each, 1-3 in a row depending on size. I  have tried adding vbNewLine, vbCrLF, and `<br>` as well as a few others but they all delete all the charts. Any ideas on how to get each chart on its own line so they are vertically stacked in the e-mail and of the same size? Here is the code. Thanks in advance:

```
Public Sub EmailCharts()
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim outMail As Object
    Set outMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim vInspector As Object
    Set vInspector = outMail.GetInspector

    Dim wEditor As Object
    Set wEditor = vInspector.WordEditor

    Dim objChart As Excel.ChartObject
 
    With outMail
        .Display
        .to = "abc@xyz.com"
        .BCC = "abc@xyz.com"
        .Subject = "Subject"
            
            For Each objChart In Sht.ChartObjects
            objChart.CopyPicture (xlBitmap)
            .HTMLBody = wEditor.Range(0, 0).Paste
            Next
    End With

    Set outMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you mixed different approaches when dealing with a `MailItem` body.

```
.HTMLBody = wEditor.Range(0, 0).Paste
```

The [Range.Paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.paste) method from the Word object model doesn't return any HTML string which can be assigned to the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property. So, you need to use one or another, but not two together. I thin the Word object model is much simpler to use (the `Paste` method), you just need to choose a different place for each image.

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Note, the [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-bodyformat-property-outlook) property allows you to programmatically change the editor that is used for the body of an item.